# Boolean always returns false

Tags: java, linked-list

I've written a loop in a method called findCar() that goes through the Linked List cars and checks whether the entered Id from user input is the same as the Id in the instances of Car, the Car instance Id is gathered from the getId() method in the Car class. However it is always returning false, does anyone know why this is? You will see references to other classes such as Clients and Person however I have omitted them for the sake of simplicity, if however having that code would assist in reaching an answer I will add it. Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Here is the Root Class

```
import java.io.*;

 public class Root
{   public Root() {

    new CarManager();

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{   new Root(); }


   private CarManager carManager;
}
```

Here is the class CarManager where the loop is called, I've marked the problem 
area with // !!

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class CarManager implements Serializable
  {   private LinkedList<Car> cars = new LinkedList<Car>();
   private Clients clients = new Clients();

   public CarManager(){

    menu();

}

  // !! Here is where the cars are initialized, the Id is the first number
     public void setup()
{   cars.add(new Car(1, "Ed", 3));
    cars.add(new Car(2, "Fred", 7));
    cars.add(new Car(3, "Freda", 5));   }


public void menu() {
    char choice;
    while ((choice = readChoice()) !='x' ) {
        switch(choice) {
            case 'a': clients.makePerson(); break;
            case 's': clients.showClients(); break;
            case 'r':clients.removeClient(); break;
            case 'b': findCar(); break;
           default: showMenu(); // break;  
        }

    }
}

private int nextInt() {

    return In.nextInt();

}

 // !! Here is where the the loop is, it checks the entered Id value and
 // !!  checks  if it matches the Id value of the car objects.                      

public void findCar() {
    System.out.println("Please enter Id of car to be found");
    int searchid = In.nextInt();
    boolean carfound = false;
    for (Car i: cars)
    { 
        if (searchid == i.getId())
        {
            carfound = true;
            System.out.println("found car");}
    } 

    if (carfound == false)
        System.out.println("Did not find car");
}

    private char readChoice() {
    System.out.print("Your choice: ");
    return In.nextChar();
}

public void exit() {

    System.exit(0);

}

}
```

And here is the Car class

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

    public class Car implements Serializable
{   
private int id;
private String pilot;
private int stops;
private LinkedList<Person> passengers = new LinkedList<Person>();
private double rate = 10.00;
public int scannableId = this.id;
//
public Car(int id, String pilot, int stops)
{   this.id = id;
    this.pilot = pilot;
    this.stops = stops;   }


private void charge(int i)
{
    //this is yet to be finished please ignore
}

private boolean stopAt(int i)
{   for (Person person: passengers)
        if (person.uses(i))
            return true;
    return false;   }

private void showStop(int i)
{   String s = "  Stop " + i + "\n";
    String on = on(i);
    if (!on.isEmpty())
        s += "    On: " + on + "\n";
    System.out.print(s);  }

private String on(int i)
{   String s = "";
    for (Person person: passengers)
        if (person.getsOn(i))
            s += person.handle() + " ";
    return s;  }
// !! Here is where the Id value is given from the instance of car
public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}


 }
```

Here is where user input is processed

```
import java.util.*;

 public class In
 {   private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static String nextLine()
{   return in.nextLine(); }

public static char nextChar()
{   return in.nextLine().charAt(0); }

public static int nextInt()
{   int i = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    return i;   }

public static double nextDouble()
{   double d = in.nextDouble();
    in.nextLine();
    return d;   }
}
```

Comment: You could use debugging outputs to check the values you compare. E. g., `System.out.println(chars.size());` and `System.out.println(chars.size(searchid);` and `System.out.println(chars.size(i.getId());` at the right places.

Comment: `println` debugging is so old school. debuggers are finally 'in things' for Java. very useful for stepping over over and inspecting state and verifying assumptions ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you never call `CarManager.setUp()` method which implies linkedlist is always empty and hence return value is always false.

Comment: I've added `setup()` under `public CarManager()` in the CarManager class, however it is still returning false, could there be another cause for this? Am I declaring the method wrong or in the wrong place?

Comment: @Mark Did you call it at the right place? Before you call `menu()`?

Comment: @glglgl I wasn't before but now I am, thanks that was the problem :) appreciate the help

Comment: @Mark Please don't edit the correction into the question - that would confuse the next reader as everything is ok now with the code.